# E-Mail to PHP Script

Tags: php, sql, email, pipe

I am trying to forward incoming emails to a php script that checks the subject and stores a record (Time Stamp, Sender) for that subject in the DB.

I am using webhostingpad as my server service with cpanel 11.

I know how to setup up the forwarding / piping to script. I have created an SQL table called 'emails' which contains only these columns: ID, Subject

Now I want the script to check the incoming email's subject with the list of subjects in the DB and then record an entry with the time stamp for the corresponding Subject column.

How do I write the script for this purpose ?

Comment: This is not a service to help you write your code. Tell us what you have done, and where your challenges are.

Comment: 1) open up your favorite IDE / texteditor 2) program what you want 3) ? 4) profit!

Comment: Bro - this was my first ever post ... Be Nice :-)

Here is the script I used for testing:
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
 
// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd))
{
 $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
 
 
mail('myemail@gmail.com','From my email pipe!','"' . $email . '"');
 
?>

Comment: I got this error:
------ pipe to |/home/******/public_html/REPORT/pipescript.php
       generated by ***@****.com ------

Error in argument 1, char 3: option not found
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
       php <file> [args...]
  -a               Run interactively
  -b <address:port>|<port> Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the code there, not in the comments. Multi-line code in comments doesn't work (just look at it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the script working by just changing the very first line in to:

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cli -c /home/USERNAME/
```